# How to implement recursive interface in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to implement interface for the following object.

```
const test:Test = {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: {
                (d... f... g... recursively),
                keyName: 1
            }
        },
        keyName: 1
    },
    keyName: 1
};
```

I tried to do like below, but I got a error.

```
interface Test {
    [key: string]: Test;
    keyName?: number; => Property 'keyName' of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to string index type 'Test'.
}
```

If you know about that, please give me solve this. Thansk for reading. :)

Comment: The type index signature has to be assignable from the types of all other properties. In other words, `[key: string]: Test | number | undefined` will work. This isn't really about recursive types so much as index types.

Comment: @Aluan Haddad Thank you for your solution :), There are additional question. If I do what you say, is it possible for other keys with number? (e.g keyName2: 1)

Comment: Sure. So long as their types are such that they could be as well accessed by the index signature. The index signature's value type has to include `number` for there to be a property of type `number`.

Comment: @Aluan Haddad I got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't defining a class that has a member of it's own type enough?

```js
class A {
    public b: A;
    public c: string;
}
```

Then you can do:

```js
let y: A;
y.b.b.b.b.b.b.b.b.b;
y.b.b.b.b.c;
```

As with any recursion you should probably stop somewhere so I'd make the recursive property optional.

Comment: This is orthogonal to classes.

Comment: I think OP wants to have any property name not just a and b

Comment: @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir Your are right. That's what I wanted.

Comment: @leftclick you might want to think it over as such a type is fairly weak. I don't know how representative your example is of your actual use, but if it is something like what you've shown, I would just let the compiler infer the type.

Comment: @Aluan Haddad Thanks for your advice. :)